# Scheduler not queuing jobs

Tags: rabbitmq, kubernetes, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I'm trying to test out Airflow on Kubernetes. The Scheduler, Worker, Queue, and Webserver are all on different deployments and I am using a Celery Executor to run my tasks.

Everything is working fine except for the fact that the Scheduler is not able to queue up jobs. Airflow is able to run my tasks fine when I manually execute it from the Web UI or CLI but I am trying to test the scheduler to make it work.

My configuration is almost the same as it is on a single server:

```
sql_alchemy_conn = postgresql+psycopg2://username:password@localhost/db
broker_url = amqp://user:password@$RABBITMQ_SERVICE_HOST:5672/vhost
celery_result_backend = amqp://user:password@$RABBITMQ_SERVICE_HOST:5672/vhost
```

I believe that with these configurations, I should be able to make it run but for some reason, only the workers are able to see the DAGs and their state, but not the scheduler, even though the scheduler is able to log their heartbeats just fine. Is there anything else I should debug or look at?

Comment: airflow have several known bugs for celery, and executors have something bugs...

Comment: @Liqiang what would you recommend then? I believe Celery is the only way to do distributed task execution

Comment: yes, Celery is the only strong and stable  distributed task execution in Python language, for my opinion, i suggest not use airflow to run, just use celery itself.

Answer (score 0):

First, you use postgres as database for airflow, don't you? Do you deploy a pod and service for postgres? If it is the case, do you verify that in your config file you have :

```
sql_alchemy_conn = postgresql+psycopg2://username:password@serviceNamePostgres/db
```

You can use this [github](https://github.com/mumoshu/kube-airflow). I used it 3 weeks ago for a first test and it worked pretty well. 
The entrypoint is useful to verify that rabbitMq and Postgres are well configured.

Comment: Yea  I've been using that image (actually a forked [version](https://github.com/Stibbons/kube-airflow/tree/helm_chart) since I'm attempting to writ a Helm chart). Everything works correctly, in the sense that I can see the heart beats to the Postgres db, but nothing is still being scheduled

Comment: Have you verified that your dags are unpaused? What is their status on the UI? Have you tried to run manually a dag in an airflow pod (kubectl exec...)? (Sorry maybe stupid question).

Comment: how would I verify my DAGs are unpaused? I turned them on, the scheduler is sending the heartbeats. Their status on the UI reflects the time when I had to run the tasks individually on the UI, so some are running, some are done. But I actually haven't ran them manually, so thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Tried running the task manually using `kubectl exec ...` The tasks were able to be distributed just fine across all CeleryWorkers and it was logged properly. However for some reason the Scheduler does not queue them up automatically (had to use `airflow backfill ...`) nor does it log that a CeleryExecutor picked up the task, like I've seen when deployed locally.